# How to remove when preload old ViewController on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am loading and opening another WKWebView in advance to reduce loading time for other webpages in Main WKWebView.

However, every time you open and close another webpage, there are more of the same page. When I close another webpage, I want to delete the closing webpage. What should I do?

**Main.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = {
apiType : "preload",
parameter : encodeURI(`view/other?value="testvalue"`)
}
webkit.messageHandlers.TestApp.postMessage(data);
...




$('#openBtn').on('click', function(){
   var data = {
apiType : "openOther"
   }
webkit.messageHandlers.TestApp.postMessage(data);
```

**MainWKWebViewController.swift**

```swift
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            case "preload":
                let parameter = message["parameter"] as! String
                preload(parameter)
                break
            case "openOther":
                openOtherScreen()
                break
...


func preload(_ prameter: String){
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   otherWebView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OtherWebViewController") as? OtherWebViewController
   otherWebView.delegate = self
   otherWebView.paramFromMain = prameter
   otherWebView.loadViewIfNeeded()
   otherWebView.otherWebView.navigationDelegate = self
   preloadCheck = true
}
func openOtherScreen(){
  if preloadCheck {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.otherWebView, animated: true)
          self.preloadCheck = false
     }
   } else {
   }
}
...
extension MainWKWebViewController: OtherWKWebViewControllerDelegate {
    func HandleData(_ key: String){
        if  key == "reload" {
            self.mainWKWebView.reload()
        }
    }
}
```

**OtherWKWebViewController.swift**

```swift
case "Close":
     self.delegate?.HandleData("reload")
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
     break
```

**Safari => Develop => TestIphone's WKwebViewList**

[image: Wkwebviewlist]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: So basically you want to open a new page with "push" animation but when the animation is done you would like to remove the previous web page?

Comment: @MaticOblak Well... it's about the same. What I want to do is to delete the closed web page when I close the preloaded web page.

Comment: @MaticOblak  As you can see from the code, when I close another webpage, I'm reloading the main webpage. Then, I'm preloading another webpage. If I can delete a page that I've opened before, that's a good idea

Comment: Well that is the problem. From the code you posted it is hard to tell what is your problem or intention. I see either 1. You are having an issue that view controllers are still present even after you call "pop" on the navigation controller. Or 2. your view controllers keep pilling up due to calling "push" and you want to preserve only one or two at the time. Or 3. something completely different.

Comment: @MaticOblak That's right. My problem is the first one Even if 'pop' is run, it still remains. So I want to delete it when I close it.

Comment: @MaticOblak However, since it is not deleted at the moment, the number is increased one by one.

Comment: Sounds interesting that this was persistent. Could you try and see which are actually persistent after the pop. Subclass your web view and your view controller (make sure you use the subclasses) and implement deinit method and see if it gets called on any of the two. It should be called on both ideally.

Comment: @MaticOblak The reason I think it's going on is because if you close a webpage from Safari's current web page list, the preload webpage doesn't disappear. You can see my picture `Safari => Develop => TestIphone's WKwebViewList` part

Comment: @MaticOblak This is my personal opinion, but I think it have a preload web page on the main web page.

Comment: @MaticOblak  Although not in the code of the current question, the main webview controller is controlling another webpage controller. For example, the color of the status bar. This is because the webview() function is not called on the controller, even if other web page navigation is completed.